# How to Restore 2 DC cluster, 3 Node on each cluster to 1 DC and 3 node cluster

Tags: cassandra-2.1

Please let me know how can we restore 2 DC cluster ( 3 node on each cluster ) to 1 DC cluster ( 3 node only). We also wants some specific keyspace to be restore on 1 DC cluster ( 3 node).

Thanks in advance.

Cheers,
Mukesh kumar

Answer (score 0):

You should use sstableloader. first, you need to create 3 node cluster with same cassandra version and then use sstableloader loader utilty. please refer below link for more details. https://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/tools/toolsBulkloader_t.html